# How to deploy Localess application in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform

How can I install the [Localess](https://github.com/Lessify/localess) open source application in firebase ?

`firebase deploy` is not working properly for me

Answer (score 0):

`firebase deploy` is not enough.

The setup process has many steps according to the docs: https://github.com/Lessify/localess/wiki/Setup